# How to detach a debugger on me in C++

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, operating-system

I'm working on a program that needed to detach its debugger automatically on the dll's side.

What I've tried is

```cpp
if (DebugActiveProcessStop(GetCurrentProcessId()))
{
...
};
```

But by `GetLastError`, I always get the error code 0x5, which means I don't have enough access to do that.

So I'm wondering how to detach the debugger from my dll?

My project on Github: https://github.com/secsome/FA2sp/blob/master/FA2sp/Miscs/Exception.cpp#L201

Comment: I think you need to provide more context before anybody can help you.

Comment: @AndersK Maybe a Github link here might be more helpful I guess? 
The main problem here is that I need to detach my program from who is a debugger made by someone else, I cannot edit the debugger. So My problem is How to detach the debugger in my own program source codes. https://github.com/secsome/FA2sp/blob/master/FA2sp/Miscs/Exception.cpp#L201

Comment: Have u checked using GetSecurityInfo to ensure you have permission for the process?

Comment: Not yet, I just thought it's not necessary as I'm just editing myself... Anyway I will try it later.

Comment: this is not *c++* question (no such thing as debugger in c++) but windows/winapi question

Comment: Please add the used OS to the tags. There is no generic way in c++ to do such things.

Answer (score 2):

for detach debugger from process need call

```
EXTERN_C
NTSYSCALLAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtRemoveProcessDebug(
    _In_ HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    _In_ HANDLE DebugObjectHandle
    );
```

the `DebugActiveProcessStop` call `DbgUiStopDebugging` which is do next:

```
NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
DbgUiStopDebugging(
    _In_ HANDLE Process
    )
{
  return NtRemoveProcessDebug(Process, NtCurrentTeb()->DbgSsReserved[1]);
}
```

but where is `DbgSsReserved[1]` set to `DebugObjectHandle` in thread *TEB* ?
inside function `DbgUiConnectToDbg` :

```
NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
DbgUiConnectToDbg()
{
    if (NtCurrentTeb()->DbgSsReserved[1])
    {
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa) };

    return NtCreateDebugObject(&NtCurrentTeb()->DbgSsReserved[1], 
        DEBUG_ALL_ACCESS, &oa, DEBUG_KILL_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

in turn `DbgUiConnectToDbg` called from `DebugActiveProcess` and from `CreateProcess[AsUser]` when `DEBUG_PROCESS` and/or `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS`

so call `DebugActiveProcessStop` have effect and exist sence only from thread which before direct or indirect (via `DebugActiveProcess` or `CreateProcess[AsUser]` with `DEBUG[_ONLY_THIS]_PROCESS` ) call `DbgUiConnectToDbg` and of course the debugger must be attached to specified process.

all this show that in your case call to `DebugActiveProcessStop` is senseless and documentation not good.

---

you need first open debug object for self process via `NtQueryInformationProcess` with `ProcessDebugObjectHandle` and then call `NtRemoveProcessDebug` on received handle. if no debugger attached to your process - `STATUS_PORT_NOT_SET` must be returned.

```
NTSTATUS StopDebugSelf()
{
    HANDLE hDebug;
    NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationProcess(NtCurrentProcess(), 
                    ProcessDebugObjectHandle, &hDebug, sizeof(HANDLE), 0);
    if (0 <= status)
    {
        status = NtRemoveProcessDebug(NtCurrentProcess(), hDebug);
        NtClose(hDebug);
    }
    return status;
}
```